# Turn off automatic backups for specific files

Tags: backup

For a long time I've had Emacs put backups for all files into a single folder:

```el
(setq backup-directory-alist '(("." . "~/.emacs.d/backups")))
```

I hardly ever visit the `backups` directory, but recently I noticed that it contains a *lot* of `*-autoloads.el` files that I don't need backups for. How can I tell Emacs not to make backups of these types of files?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can customize the location through [`backup-directory-alist`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Backup-Names.html). Each entry in the list says where to put the backups of files matching a pattern; if the location is `nil`, the backup will be in the same directory as the original. The order matters: the first match is used.

```
(setq backup-directory-alist '(("-autoloads\\.el\\'")
                               ("." . "~/.emacs.d/backups")))
```

If you want to suppress backups altogether on the basis of the file name or location, there doesn't appear to be a built-in mechanism for that, but it's easy enough to add. The variable [`backup-enable-predicate`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Making-Backups.html#index-backup_002denable_002dpredicate-2070) contains the name of a function that determines whether a file should have backups. The default setting `normal-backup-enable-predicate` only inhibits backups in the directories that Emacs uses for temporary files. You can add your own function that checks the file name as well.

```
(defvar backup-inhibit-file-name-regexp "-autoloads\\.el\\'"
  "Files whose full path matches this regular expression will not be backed up.")
(defun regexp-backup-enable-predicate (filename)
  "Disable backups for files whose name matches `backup-inhibit-file-name-regexp'.
Also call `normal-backup-enable-predicate'."
  (save-match-data
    (and (not (string-match backup-inhibit-file-name-regexp filename))
     (normal-backup-enable-predicate filename))))
(setq backup-enable-predicate 'regexp-backup-enable-predicate)
```

Even if this function returns `t`, other mechanisms can disable backups.

If you want to disable backups in a specific major mode, set [`make-backup-files`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Making-Backups.html#index-make_002dbackup_002dfiles-2069) to `nil` in the major mode's setup hook (possibly based on the file name and other characteristics). Don't forget to make the variable buffer-local.

Another way to disable backups for certain files is to set [`backup-inhibited`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Making-Backups.html#index-backup_002dinhibited-2072). This variable survives a major mode change. It's how VC disables backups on files under version control (through an entry in `file-find-hook`). Don't forget to make the variable buffer-local.

Comment: Which pattern should I use to disable it for the files `*/.git\COMMIT_EDITMSG`?

Comment: @alper The regexp needs to match that specific suffix in the file's full name (with the directory part), and `.` needs to be quoted in a regexp, so: `(setq backup-directory-alist '(("/\\.git/COMMIT_EDITMSG\\'")`

Comment: Thanks if I've multiple files can I add in to the alist one after another like `("" . "")` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to **avoid backups for a single file**, you can use the line

```
# -*- backup-inhibited:1 -*-
```

at the top of the file, where `#` is the comment style for that file.

See https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables and https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Making-Backups.html#index-backup_002dinhibited-2072 .